# Login via Facebook into OpenAM using REST

Tags: spring, facebook, rest, authentication, openam

I am looking forward to integrate logging in users using Facebook's authentication. I have my app protected by OpenAM and the users are already registered there. I have my own login page and would not like to move this to OpenAM and retain it in my app. As of now, I am using REST calls to authenticate users in OpenAM. Now, I want to integrate login using Facebook. My idea of implementation is as following:

1. User logs in using original credentials and is authenticated in
   OpenAM.
2. User is asked to associate his/her Facebook account with the
       OpenAM account.
3. User authenticates his/her Facebook account
           (https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?app_id={app-id-as-created-in-fb-developers-console}&redirect_uri={my-rest-service}).
4. This will return the code and that can be used to recheck against
   Facebook to ensure that the user was authenticated against my app
   and this is not a hacker intervention
   (http://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?%20input_token={code-returned-from-facebook}&access_token={my-app's-access-token}.
   The response will contain the app ID that can be verified against my
   App's ID. On success, I shall call OpenAM to associate the user in
   OpenAM with his/her Facebook credentials **(Not sure what all to use
   here.)**
5. Next, whenever the user wants to login, he/she can use Facebook
   login where in the redirect URL would be my REST service and the
   code returned from Facebook can be rechecked from Facebook and then
   OpenAM will be called to authenticate.

My queries:

1. I am not sure if this approach is feasible.
2. How do I pair an existing user in OpenAM with the Facebook account?
3. How do I authenticate the user in OpenAM after Facebook login, with
   the userID?
4. Is the Facebook userID (numeric,returned from Facebook graph in JSON
   response), unique and permanent?
5. I would also want to give the users an option to de-associate the
   existing Facebook account and associate a new one-how do I do this?

Apologies for asking too many questions, but I am new to OpenAM and OAuth and keen on following the approach I have mentioned above.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an aside, it will probably be much easier in the future if you delegate all of the login to OpenAM, and let it deal with local login and social. This will make it really easy to add more social providers.

If you want to keep your current architecture, you can create a new authentication chain in OpenAM that just has social (facebook) login. You should be able to redirect the user to that chain. Once the social login process is complete, you can have OpenAM redirect back to your application page.

To link local and social login you are going to have to offer some kind of account claiming in your application.  After they do a social login you could ask them to link their local account by providing the username and password. You can call OpenAM's REST API to validate the credentials.

This kind of linking can be confusing for users - so sometimes it is better to treat them as separate accounts, or have a migration process for the user to migrate to social only.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Warren.Much appreciated. I have been able to figure out a way to authenticate my user in facebook and receive the token back. My query now is to authenticate my user in OpenAM without using his/her credentials, but this token only (or anything else that can be returned from Facebook). Also, I am looking at your option to authenticate user using a new chain. It would be really helpful if you could please throw more light on it with details like how to authenticate the user in the new chain?

Comment: You need to let OpenAM handle the facebook authentication if you want the user to authenticate to OpenAM without a password. You can invoke an alternate authentication chain by using the  ?service=chain parameter when you send the user to OpenAM for authentication.  Try setting up social authentication in OpenAM- it should become clearer

Comment: Thanks a lot, Warren. Things are getting better now. I have set up Authentication Chaining and I am able to authenticate the user using Facebook login. Any idea how can I get the iPlanetDirectoryPro Cookie from this chain. My application checks for this cookie through out and hence it is mandatory that I get this as a token for successful login.

Comment: Thank you, for all your help, Warren. I am almost done, I guess. I need to figure out how to get a token for successful authentication and how to map the email-address from facebook to that in OpenAM. I am trying to authenticate the user in OpenAM if the email address from Facebook, matches that in OpenAM. Any leads on that? Thanks

Comment: I am sorry I have been asking way too many questions. I have configured the chain authentication but I am not getting redirected to the correct page for successful/failed login. I am getting redirected to the login page of my app even though the redirect URLs are not pointing to the login page. Could you please suggest what could be wrong in my configuration?

Comment: Some more information:
I have two authentication chains and the older one has the criteria set to "required" and the one I created for login via Facebook has the criteria set to "sufficient".

Comment: Hi Warren, I am almost done with all the configurations. My app updates OpenAM's email field with the Facebook ID (not email ID, the actual numeric ID) to associate users with their Facebook account. This part works fine.
However, my users are not getting authenticated using this and I am always redirected to the login failure page. In my configuration I have added account mapper as org.forgerock.openam.authentication.modules.oauth2.DefaultAccountMapper|id|facebook-
and Account Mapper Configuration has email=facebook-id.
Am I missing something?
It would be of great help if u could clarify.